# How to call methods in Java within the same class and system.out.print the result

Tags: java, bluej

I need to print the startPrice, then a tab then the cost of carpet(I have written a return method for this already but not sure how to call it) then a tab and then the cost of the fitting.

Here are the return methods:

```
private double calculateCarpetCost(int length, int width, double price) {
    return (length * width) * price;
}

private double calculateFittingCost (int length, int width, double price, double costMultiplier){
   return (length * width) * labourCharge; 
}
```

This is what I have done but everytime I execute it, instead of a value. The title shows up. eg.. carpetcostestimator.getdoubleprice...instead of the price.eg 50. How do I use the methods above to call method and get an answer.

```
System.out.print("CarpetCostEstimator.getdoubleprice" +
                 "\t\t" + 
                 "getcalculateCarpetCost" +
                 "\t");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. The only print statement you are showing ... prints two **strings**. That statement does NOT at all invoke any of your methods. You need `... print("Here string: " + someMethod(parm1, parm2));`

Comment: Use `private static double` for a method on class level (without CarpetCostEstimator object instance).

Answer (score 0):

Question lacks information.

Although, You're printing both of your methods as Strings. Remove double quotes from both of your method calls.

```
System.out.print(CarpetCostEstimator.getdoubleprice +"\t\t"+getcalculateCarpetCost"+"\t");
```

Answer (score 0):

It prints that way because you provided a string instead of calling the method.

The right sout should be:

```
System.out.println(getDoublePrice() + "\t\t" + calculateCarpetCost());
```

You can not invoke a method on the class name unless it's a static method. If you want to use the current object, you can use **this.** keyword